# How to use "link_to" instead of "checkbox" for POST?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, model-view-controller

[image]

The idea is that when the user has a `missed_day` (aka a strike) he would click this button. He can currently click a checkbox to mark a `missed_day`.

[image]

**habits/show**

```
<div class="strikes">
  <% if @habit.current_level_strike %> 
    <div class="btn" id="red"> <label id="<%= @habit.id %>" class="habit-id">Strikes:</label>
  <% else %> 
    <div class="btn" id="gold"> <label id="<%= @habit.id %>" class="habit-id-two">Strikes:</label>
  <% end %>
    <% @habit.levels.each_with_index do |level, index| %>
      <% if @habit.current_level >= (index + 1) %>
        <p data-submit-url="<%= habit_level_days_missed_index_path({ habit_id: @habit.id, level_id: level.id }) %>"
           data-delete-url="<%= habit_level_days_missed_path({ habit_id: @habit.id, level_id: level.id, id: 1 }) %>">
          <% if @habit.current_level_strike %> 
            <label id="<%= level.id %>" class="level-id">Level <%= index + 1 %>:</label> 
          <% else %> 
            <label id="<%= level.id %>" class="level-id-two">Level <%= index + 1 %>:</label> 
          <% end %>
          <%= check_box_tag nil, true, level.missed_days > 0, {class: "habit-check"} %>
          <%= check_box_tag nil, true, level.missed_days > 1, {class: "habit-check"} %>
          <%= check_box_tag nil, true, level.missed_days > 2, {class: "habit-check"} %>
       </p>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**habit.js**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $(".habit-check").change(function()
  {
    var submitUrl = $(this).parents("p").data("submit-url");
    var deleteUrl = $(this).parents("p").data("delete-url");

    if($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
       $.ajax(
       {
         url: submitUrl,
         method: "POST"
       })
       .done(function () {
         location.reload();
       });
    }
    else
    {
       $.ajax(
       {
         url: deleteUrl,
         method: "DELETE"
       })
       .done(function () {
         location.reload();
       });
    }
  });
});
```

**days_missed_controller**

```
class DaysMissedController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def create
    habit = Habit.find(params[:habit_id])
    habit.missed_days = habit.missed_days + 1
    @habit.save!
    level = habit.levels.find(params[:level_id])
    level.missed_days = level.missed_days + 1
    if level.missed_days == 3
      level.missed_days = 0
      level.days_lost += habit.calculate_days_lost + 2
    end
    level.save!
    head :ok # this returns an empty response with a 200 success status code
  end

  def destroy
    habit = Habit.find(params[:habit_id])
    habit.missed_days = habit.missed_days - 1
    @habit.save!
    level = habit.levels.find(params[:level_id])
    level.missed_days = level.missed_days - 1
    level.save!
    head :ok # this returns an empty response with a 200 success status code
  end

private

  def correct_user
    @habit = current_user.habits.find(params[:habit_id])
    redirect_to habits_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this habit" if @habit.nil?
  end
end
```

The 1st pic is from the home page. Here is the code for the two buttons:

```
<%= link_to '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>'.html_safe, mark_completed_path(habit), remote: true, method: 'put', class: 'update_habit', id: 'home_check' %>
<%= link_to '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>'.html_safe, habit_level_days_missed_index_path({ habit_id: @habit.id, level_id: level.id }), remote: true, method: 'put', class: 'habit-check' %>
```

How can we get this 2nd button to work? This attempt gave me `undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass`

Here's the **[Gist](http://gist.github.com/RallyWithGalli/c66dee6dfb9ab5d338c2)** of it.

Comment: what response do you get from ajax in your dev tools resources tab?

Comment: Do you have those links under the loop? Then try `<%= link_to '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>'.html_safe, habit_level_days_missed_index_path({ habit_id: habit, level_id: level.id }), remote: true, method: 'put', class: 'habit-check' %>`

Comment: Hi @Pavan. Your code gives: `undefined local variable or method 'level' for #<#<Class:0x007fe6d0a42248>:0x007fe6d6e3e080>` so I made level into `@level.id` but that gave `undefined method 'level' for #<Habit:0x007fe6cb970f18>`. I think I need a way to rewrite this line I used in the show page: `<% @habit.levels.each_with_index do |level, index| %>` to move to the home page. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did your problem solved?

Comment: No @Pavan it didn't work. Trying different things.

Comment: Can you post corresponding controller action for that view page? And if possible please update with full view code.

Comment: I updated the gist @Pavan :] The view page is habits/_habits.html.erb where I'm trying to add the button. And that is being rendered by pages/home.html.erb `<%= render @habits %>` The controller action is `def home @habits = current_user.habits.committed_for_today.incomplete.order(:order) end`

Comment: Try changing `habit = Habit.find(params[:habit_id])` to `@habit = Habit.find(params[:habit_id])` and `level = habit.levels.find(params[:level_id])` to `@level = habit.levels.find(params[:level_id])` in `create` method of `days_missed_controller` and use in the link `<%= link_to '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>'.html_safe, habit_level_days_missed_index_path({ habit_id: @habit.id, level_id: @level.id }), remote: true, method: 'put', class: 'habit-check' %>`

Comment: Unfortunately that still gives: `undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass` @Pavan

Comment: oops. Sorry try this `@level = @habit.levels.find(params[:level_id])` instead of `@level = habit.levels.find(params[:level_id])` and check

Comment: Darn same thing :/ @Pavan

Comment: I understood now. How your pages/home method looks like?

Comment: Awesome. It's `<%= render @habits %>` that calls the partial

Comment: @Pavan the method looks like this: `@habits = current_user.habits.committed_for_today.incomplete.order(:order)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84496/discussion-between-pavan-and-anthonygalli-com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this link

```
<%= link_to '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>'.html_safe, habit_level_days_missed_index_path({ habit_id: @habit.id, level_id: level.id }), remote: true, method: 'put', class: 'habit-check' %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>'.html_safe, habit_level_days_missed_index_path({ habit_id: habit, level_id: habit.current_level }), remote: true, method: 'put', class: 'habit-check' %>
```

Comment: Thanks again Pavan! I'll continue the conversation over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685983/recordnotfound-couldnt-find-level-with-id