# RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Level with "id"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Having some trouble fixing this error:

```
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Level with 'id'=1 [WHERE "levels"."habit_id" = ?]):
  app/controllers/days_missed_controller.rb:9:in `create'
```

when clicking on this button:

```
<%= link_to '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>'.html_safe, habit_level_days_missed_index_path({ habit_id: habit, level_id: habit.current_level }), remote: true, method: 'post', class: 'habit-check' %>    #    habits/_habit.html.erb, which is rendered by <%= render @habits %> in pages/home.html.erb
```

[image]

**days_missed_controller**

```
  def create
    habit = Habit.find(params[:habit_id])
    habit.missed_days = habit.missed_days + 1
    @habit.save!
    level = habit.levels.find(params[:level_id])
    level.missed_days = level.missed_days + 1
    if level.missed_days == 3
      level.missed_days = 0
      level.days_lost += habit.calculate_days_lost + 2
    end
    level.save!
    head :ok # this returns an empty response with a 200 success status code
  end
```

Here's the **[Gist](https://gist.github.com/RallyWithGalli/c66dee6dfb9ab5d338c2)** of it.

This question is coming off of @Pavan's **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31665081/how-to-use-link-to-instead-of-checkbox-for-post)**. We couldn't figure out how to solve this error together so we'd greatly appreciate your input!

Comment: just out of curiosity, why you need to send level_id when you can use habit.current_level in the action.

Comment: Like if I just do `habit_level_days_missed_index_path(habit.current_level)` @Athar? That would give the error `No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"days_missed", :format=>nil, :habit_id=>5, :level_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:level_id]`

Comment: okay so you have made level_id compulsory to be passed to the create action.? i was talking about using like this
`<%= link_to '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>'.html_safe, habit_level_days_missed_index_path(habit_id: habit, level_id), remote: true, method: 'post', class: 'habit-check' %> `

Comment: and in the action. you can do something like this `level = habit.levels.where(id: habit.current_level)`

Comment: according to the error i see. habit.current_level is 1 and there is no level for that habit with level_id 1.

Comment: @Athar there is a level_id with 1.

Comment: is it assosiated with that habit as well.?

Comment: And for example this works `<% habit.levels.each do |level| %> 
            <%= link_to '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>'.html_safe, habit_level_days_missed_index_path({ habit_id: habit, level_id: level.id }), remote: true, method: 'post', class: 'habit-check' %> 
          <% end %>` but then the button is duplicated 5 times because of the looping. I just need one button to show that would affect the current level when clicked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84506/discussion-between-athar-and-anthonygalli-com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add method `current_habit_level` in habit.rb which will use current_level and fetch level_id for that habit. So that when you click the link it will pass correct level is and it won't crash on searching

```
  def current_habit_level
    self.levels.order("id asc").limit(current_level).last
 end
```

Use this method to fetch level id in link